# How to get rid of Infragisitic 6.1 installation Error 1609 - ASPNET is not a valid user or group?

Tags: visual-studio, iis-7, infragistics

I am getting an Error 1609 - ASPNET is not a valid user or group while installing infragistic 6.1.. 
I'hv IIS7 & Visual studio 2013 installed..
While creating ASPNET user by using this command getting error: aspnet_regiis is not recognized as an internal or external command..
Any idea?

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322
aspnet_regiis –i
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still need assistance how to fix the mentioned issue, you could find information about fixing 1609 error, in the forum below:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/65220/330538.aspx

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Go to this path and open "Computer Management".

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\Computer Management.lnk

**2.** refer attached image and do the changes

[image]